# Rolling up multiple rows into a single row and column in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark DF as below. I need to roll up multiple rows with same ID as single row but the values should be distinct.

```
id|values
1 |hello
1 |hello Sam
1 |hello Tom
2 |hello
2 |hello Tom
```

Expected Output

```
id|values
1 |hello, Sam, Tom
2 |hello, Tom
```

I am done with the rollup part but how to filter the duplicate tokens?

Current code:

```
df.select("id","values")
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list("values")))
```

**2nd part of the question:**
i also tried via SQL but its showing also the duplicates.

```
spark.sql("select id, concat_ws(' ' ,collect_set(values)) as values from data group by id ").show(false)
+---+----------------------------+
|id |values                      |
+---+----------------------------+
|1  |hello hello Sam hello Tom   |
|2  |hello hello Tom             |
+---+----------------------------+
```

How to get rid of duplicates in above query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `collect_set` as

`df.select("id","values").groupBy("id").agg(concat_ws(",",collect_set("values")))`

**UPDATE:**

If you have String separated with space then above doesn't work

You need to split with the space and find the distinct using udf as below

```
val tokenize = udf((value: Seq[String]) => {
  value.flatMap(_.split(",|\\s+")).map(_.trim).distinct
})

df.select("id", "values").groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("values").as("value"))
    .withColumn("value1", tokenize($"value"))

.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+-----------------+
|id |value            |
+---+-----------------+
|1  |[hello, Sam, Tom]|
|2  |[hello, Tom]     |
+---+-----------------+
```

Comment: what us the type of your values ? Array[String] or a single string ?

Comment: for now its single string[separated by spaces], but it can be an Array[String] also

Comment: If it is a single string separated by spaces then this wont work, You need udf to make it distinct.

Comment: I know its not a right question to ask in this forum, but can you please help me with that?

Comment: It cannot have both array[string] and single string at the same time, What will you have is only one ?Then I can help you out

Comment: for now its a  string with spaces. like `hello sam`

Comment: @Shibu: First use `split` to split the string on space, then you can use the above solution.

Comment: Thanks. let me check

Comment: @ShankarKoirala why have you used `.split(",|\\s+")`, instead of just `.split(" ")`

Comment: Oh you can use `.split(" ")` I just used it to seperate with both comma and space.

Comment: @ShankarKoirala in case its a single string, that what needs to be changed ?

Comment: If you have a single word and no array then you can directly use `collect_set()`

Comment: i have used the same in the below spark sql query ,but its returning duplicates. i have edited the question. please check.
`spark.sql("select id, concat_ws(' ' ,collect_set(values)) as values from data group by id ").show(false)`

Comment: Do you have the same input as before?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171204/discussion-between-shankar-koirala-and-shibu).

Answer (score 1):

For folks looking for a 100% sql solution, something like this worked for me to generate a comma delimited string representation of the list I was looking for:

```
select  
  patient_id, 
  concat_ws(",", collect_set(distinct encounter_id)) enc_list, 
  count(distinct encounter_id) enc_count
from
  encounter 
group by 1;
```