# pyspark pivot without aggregation function

Tags: pyspark

I am new to pyspark and I am trying to get from here:

```
+---+-----+--------+
| id|value|ordering|
+---+-----+--------+ 
| A | 21  | 1      |
| A | 22  | 2      |
| A | 23  | 3      |
| A | 24  | 4      |
| B | 15  | 1      |
| B | 16  | 2      |
| B | 10  | 3      |
| B | 10  | 4      |
+---+-----+--------+
```

to here:

```
+---+-------+-------+-------+----------+
| id|value_0|value_1|value_n| value_n+1|
+---+-------+-------+-------+----------+
| A | 21    | 22    | 23    |  24      |
| B | 15    | 16    | 10    |  10      |
+---+-------+-------+-------+----------+
```

I tried using pivot, but I don't need to aggregate, and I don't understand how to do it without aggregation. I also tried approach outlined here [Rolling up multiple rows into a single row and column in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50366363/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-in-spark), and then split col into multiple cols, but I need to keep the order of elements as they appear in the dataframe (I have extra column -'ordering'- I can use to `orderBy`). I can't do it with this approach as `concat_ws` doesn't preserve order + I can have repetitions.

Any help appreciated

Comment: please add the dataframes directly in the question rather than a link. also, please share it with the ordering column.

Comment: what would happen if the original data contained two entries with the same `id` and `ordering`? Which `value` would be the correct one?

Comment: @samkart I edited once more. Ordering and id are of the different types and forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `first` function as the aggregation.

Can we use the `ordering` field directly to create `"value_1"`, `"value_2"`, so on? If yes, see following.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('pivot_field', func.concat_ws('_', func.lit('value'), 'ordering')). \
    groupBy('id'). \
    pivot('pivot_field'). \
    agg(func.first('value')). \
    show()

# +---+-------+-------+-------+-------+
# | id|value_1|value_2|value_3|value_4|
# +---+-------+-------+-------+-------+
# |  B|     15|     16|     10|     10|
# |  A|     21|     22|     23|     24|
# +---+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

If not, create a column with the `row_number` and use that. See following.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('rn', func.row_number().over(wd.partitionBy('id').orderBy('ordering'))). \
    withColumn('pivot_field', func.concat_ws('_', func.lit('value'), 'rn')). \
    groupBy('id'). \
    pivot('pivot_field'). \
    agg(func.first('value')). \
    show()

# +---+-------+-------+-------+-------+
# | id|value_1|value_2|value_3|value_4|
# +---+-------+-------+-------+-------+
# |  B|     15|     16|     10|     10|
# |  A|     21|     22|     23|     24|
# +---+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

This assumes that the data is unique across the columns being used here - as in all values within an ID will have distinct values in ordering. If not, you could change the aggregation to your choice.

Comment: Wow, thx! 1 follow up, how would I change the agg if they are not unique, if there are lots of repetitions for each of the id?

Comment: @lurii it depends on how you want the values? do you want them as a list? Use collect_list instead of first. Max? max(). Average? avg(). etc.

Comment: also, if you're using the second method, change row_number() to dense_rank()